# How can I handle long Int with GraphQL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, bigint

As you know that GraphQL has no data type like long int. So, whenever the number is something big like `10000000000`, it throws an error like this: `Int cannot represent non 32-bit signed integer value: 1000000000000`

For that I know two solutions:

1. Use scalars.

```js
import { GraphQLScalarType } from 'graphql';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema';

const myCustomScalarType = new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'MyCustomScalar',
  description: 'Description of my custom scalar type',
  serialize(value) {
    let result;
    return result;
  },
  parseValue(value) {
    let result;
    return result;
  },
  parseLiteral(ast) {
    switch (ast.kind) {
    }
  }
});

const schemaString = `

scalar MyCustomScalar

type Foo {
  aField: MyCustomScalar
}

type Query {
  foo: Foo
}

`;

const resolverFunctions = {
  MyCustomScalar: myCustomScalarType
};

const jsSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: schemaString,
  resolvers: resolverFunctions,
});
```

2. Use [apollo-type-bigint package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-type-bigint).

Both of those solutions convert the big int to `string`, and I'd rather not use string (I prefer a number type).

Comment: What do you mean by "*convert the big int to string*"?

Comment: Means if i use this method then the data should be like `{ "a": "10000000000" }` but it should be. `{"a" : 1000000000}`

Comment: It's pretty hard to parse JSON with too-long numbers, so it's easier to put them in strings. Given any integer type with more than 32 bits will be a custom scalar anyway, it should hardly matter.

Comment: So, my first approach will be fine for the implementation? or do you have any other options?

Comment: Well, the code snippet you posted doesn't yet actually do anything, but yes all approaches will be based on using a custom scalar type.

Comment: can you show me an example? that would be helpful. thanks

Comment: Take a look at the sources of any of the bigint-graphql js libraries out there

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Correct, there's no concept like `bigInt` in `graphQL`.

You can try one of these:

1. Set type as `Float` instead of `Int` - it will handle all large int values and also send them as `number`
   [below are technically options, although you stated you don't like `string` solutions]
2. Set type as `String`, as you described
3. Give (an npm-provided data type, like) `BigInt`, as you described. It will handle big int, but will convert your values into `string`

npm BigInt dependency with Graphql v16 support:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-scalars, docs: https://www.the-guild.dev/graphql/scalars/docs/scalars/big-int

Comment: will check the float thing.

Comment: "*`Float` will handle all large int values*" - until 53 bits, that is.

Comment: @HarshPatel Not really that bit, though. 64 and 128 bit integers are common as well.

Comment: I notice one thing that if I make data type as float it will handle any big number, I don't understand why. but its strange behavior. like I check for `1B` and `10B`

Answer (score 10):

Graphql has introduced Scalars. I am using Java and so I can provide some solution in Java. You can achieve the same by following the below steps.

in your .graphqls file please define scalar

```
scalar Long

type Movie{
movieId: String
movieName: String
producer: String
director: String
demoId : Long
}
```

Now you have to register this scalar in your wiring.

```
return RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring().type("Query", typeWiring -> typeWiring
                .dataFetcher("allMovies", allMoviesDataFetcher).dataFetcher("movie", movieDataFetcher)
                .dataFetcher("getMovie", getMovieDataFetcher)).scalar(ExtendedScalars.GraphQLLong).build();
```

Now you have to define the Scalar configuration for Long as below.

```
@Configuration
public class LongScalarConfiguration {
     @Bean
        public GraphQLScalarType longScalar() {
            return GraphQLScalarType.newScalar()
                .name("Long")
                .description("Java 8 Long as scalar.")
                .coercing(new Coercing<Long, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String serialize(final Object dataFetcherResult) {
                        if (dataFetcherResult instanceof Long) {
                            return dataFetcherResult.toString();
                        } else {
                            throw new CoercingSerializeException("Expected a Long object.");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Long parseValue(final Object input) {
                        try {
                            if (input instanceof String) {
                                return new Long((String) input);
                            } else {
                                throw new CoercingParseValueException("Expected a String");
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            throw new CoercingParseValueException(String.format("Not a valid Long: '%s'.", input), e
                            );
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Long parseLiteral(final Object input) {
                        if (input instanceof StringValue) {
                            try {
                                return new Long(((StringValue) input).getValue());
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                throw new CoercingParseLiteralException(e);
                            }
                        } else {
                            throw new CoercingParseLiteralException("Expected a StringValue.");
                        }
                    }
                }).build();
        }

}
```

It should solve your problem. Please give it a try for Java related application.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [graphql-bigint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-bigint) package in this case. This implementation gives you 53-bit integers. Any integer-like number above 52bit will have it's lower values truncated. So if you need it above 52bit, using strings would be safer.

Comment: How is this better than/different from the apollo-type-bigint package that the OP considered to use?

Comment: apollo-type-bigint has two implementions. The first one works with only with 53 bit integers. The second implementation allows you to work with 63 bit integers using a new data type in JavaScript - BigInt. graphql-bigint is simplier, and if I understood the question correctly, it should do the work that OP needs. Though there is nothing wrong with using apollo-type-bigint

Answer (score -1):

There is not BigInt in graphql/apollo but you can make your custom scalar to support this.

```
const typeDef = gql`
  scalar BigInt
  type Mutation {
    .....
  }
`
```

If you are using typescript you can add the declare, or omit it if js.

```
declare global {
  interface BigInt {
    toJSON: () => number;
    fromJSON: () => BigInt;
  }
}

BigInt.prototype.toJSON = function () {
  const int = Number.parseInt(this.toString());
  return int ?? this.toString();
};

BigInt.prototype.fromJSON = function () {
  return BigInt(this.toString());
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create custom scalar type of your own.

Define your scalar in `your-schema.graphql`

```
scalar BigInt
```

After that write your resolver

```
import { GraphQLScalarType } from "graphql";

const resolver = {
  BigInt: new GraphQLScalarType({
    name: "BigInt",
    description: "BigInt custom scalar type",
    serialize(value) {
      return Number(value);
    },
    parseValue(value) {
      return BigInt(value);
    },
    parseLiteral(ast) {
      return ast.kind === Kind.INT ? BigInt(ast.value) : null;
    },
  }),
};

export default resolver;
```

Now you can use BigInt in your schemas as any other scalar.

```
type Record {
  count: BigInt!
}
```

#### Additional Context:

This works for my use case (ethers.js solidity uint responses) but you may face with precision loose when using >32 bit floats.
To solve that issue, you can serialize your value to string instead of Number and return stringified value to your clients.

Comment: If you are using a `BigInt` type, you should provide real big integers not ones that are serialised to a floating point number. People would expect to be able to pass values with more than 64 bit.

Comment: What do u mean? You can that way? This has nothing to do with a floating point number?

Comment: Your `serialise` method mangles the bigint so that it looses precision

Comment: Yes, what of it. If your GraphQL Server returns a BigInt which there is no built-in way to return BigInt values it's just converting a BigInt value to a Number. And the opposite, converts value from the client to BigInt. I don't understand what's your point. That's the point of having `BigInt`. If you want precision, you should use Float anyways.

Comment: Without [JSON source text access](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-json-parse-with-source), you could at least serialise to a string, instead of using lossy serialiation. "*If you want precision, you should use Float anyways.*" - absolutely not!

Comment: Ok I think now I got your point. But I don't want to return string to the client. It needs to be number. I have my values as `BigInt` but they're not real BigInts, not greater than 32 bits. That's my use case. What i mean about float is that, you can just create another scalar for >32bits floats.

Comment: Then please [edit] your answer so that it points out clearly it's only supposed to work with small big ints.